# VBA Word : SmartArts and range

Tags: vba, ms-word, shapes

I'm currently working with SmartArts in Word.
The SmartArt already exists, and I would like to find a way to access a SmartArt value from a range, Office cursor (so Selection) or something akin to it.

Here's my SmartArt.
To be exact, the SmartArtLayout is Application.SmartArtLayouts(88)

[image: SmartArt tree]

What I can do already :

- Create a SmartArt on my Document, keep it as a Shape to work on it.
- Looping on all the Nodes of my SmartArt, selecting the ones I want to keep, and inserting the ones I want to keep in a database, with a link to their parent.

Now I'm blocked on something.
I want to find a Way to edit/delete a particular node, both in DB and in the SmartArt.
It would be possible if I made a Userform that put every Shape Text in a drop-down list, and I then looped on all shapes to find the shape with the chosen text in it.

[image: Userform]

If noone answers, that'll probably be what I am going to do. 
But I don't find this way natural or practical.

So I'm looking for a method to be able to find the Node that have the cursor on it. I would've done something like that :

```
'Putting my SmartArt in SAShape
For Each Node In SAShape.SmartArt.AllNodes
    If (Selection.Range.InRange(Node.Range)) Then
        'my code
    End If
Next Node
```

But It'd have been too easy... The shapes don't seem to have a range.

Is there a way to get the Node with focus, or to get the node we clicked on?
Thanks in advance!

Cordially,

Answer (score 1):

firt It not like Question but it is task but i will give you some hint to help you

1) to get any node in any level loop will be like this

```
 Set oShape = ActiveSheet.Shapes(1)
For i = 1 To oShape.SmartArt.AllNodes.Count
  oShape.SmartArt.AllNodes(i).TextFrame2.TextRange.Text = "Sample " & i
Next
```

2)To Get specific node for delete or edit you must determine an id i can not do that perfect but i assign the id to alt text when i add alt text i can find any node

2.1) when shearch

```
 nod.TextFrame2.TextRange.Text = str
 nod.Shapes(1).AlternativeText = index
```

2.2) when check for search

```
  If oShape.SmartArt.AllNodes(i).Shapes(1).AlternativeText = index
```

and the imge will show where alt store

[image: alt text in excel]

[image]

that i think will help you in some way for do what you need but you must understand how smart art tree change after item delete

[smartart](/questions/tagged/smartart)

Comment: Wow man I was searching for this one property Alternative text for years!!! Now I can finally compare two nodes and do lot of validations : )